# Redirect loop trying to view another user's draft

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/drafts/6817 redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/188/objects?draftId=6817, which redirects back, and so on, until the browser gives up.

Comment: Same issue as in [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328213/redirect-loop-trying-to-view-another-users-draft).

Comment: @Bhar Then you should vote to close as duplicate ;)

Comment: @nicael I voted to close the other as a dupe of this ;)

Comment: @Bhar Oh that's certainly not right. Despite of the fact that one is a newer question, it has got better answers, so you should vote to close *this* one.

Comment: This is a link-only question and not spam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.

Answer (score 2):

I found this problem by clicking on the title of a proposed change. For the author, it usefully takes them back to the draft, but for other users, it falls into the redirect loop. There is a read-only draft mode I see on my own approved proposed changes, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/558/introduction-to-oracle?draftId=4659):

[image: Read only Hello World]

Perhaps that mode could be extended to other users looking at an author's draft? In addition to fixing the redirect loop, I bet that would be useful on occasion.